# librosa.feature.delta() illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, wav, librosa

I am working on a .wav signals using python 3.5 and trying to extract mfcc, mfcc delta, mfcc delta-deltas, and other signal features. but there is an error raised only with mfcc delta with is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    mfcc_delta = librosa.feature.delta(mfcc)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\librosa\feature\utils.py", line 116, in delta
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\_savitzky_golay.py", line 337, in savgol_filter
    coeffs = savgol_coeffs(window_length, polyorder, deriv=deriv, delta=delta)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\_savitzky_golay.py", line 139, in savgol_coeffs
    coeffs, _, _, _ = lstsq(A, y)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py", line 1226, in lstsq
    % (-info, lapack_driver))
ValueError: illegal value in 4-th argument of internal None
```

I am working on the following code:

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
import librosa
from scipy import signal
import scipy.stats

def preprocess_cough(x,fs, cutoff = 6000, normalize = True, filter_ = True, downsample = True): 
    #Preprocess Data
    if len(x.shape)>1:
        x = np.mean(x,axis=1)                          # Convert to mono
    if normalize:
        x = x/(np.max(np.abs(x))+1e-17)                # Norm to range between -1 to 1
    if filter_:
        b, a = butter(4, fs_downsample/fs, btype='lowpass') # 4th order butter lowpass filter
        x = filtfilt(b, a, x)
    if downsample:
        x = signal.decimate(x, int(fs/fs_downsample)) # Downsample for anti-aliasing
    
    fs_new = fs_downsample

    return np.float32(x), fs_new

audio_data = 'F:/test/'
files = librosa.util.find_files(audio_data, ext=['wav'])
x,fs = librosa.load(myFile,sr=48000)
arr, f = preprocess_cough(x,fs)
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=arr, sr=f, n_mfcc=13)
mfcc_delta = librosa.feature.delta(mfcc)
mfcc_delta2 = librosa.feature.delta(mfcc, order=2)
```

when I remove the mffcs calculations and calculate the other wav signal features the error does not appear again. Also, I have tried to remove `n_mfcc=13` parameter but the error still raises.

Sample of the output and the shape of mfcc variable

```
[-3.86701782e+02 -4.14421021e+02 -4.67373749e+02 -4.76989105e+02
  -4.23713501e+02 -3.71329285e+02 -3.47003693e+02 -3.19309082e+02
  -3.29547089e+02 -3.32584625e+02 -2.78399109e+02 -2.43284348e+02
  -2.47878128e+02 -2.59308533e+02 -2.71102844e+02 -2.87314514e+02
  -2.58869965e+02 -6.01125565e+01  1.66160011e+01 -8.58060551e+00
  -8.49179382e+01 -9.29880371e+01 -9.96001358e+01 -1.04499428e+02
  -3.65511665e+01 -3.82106819e+01 -8.69802475e+01 -1.22267052e+02
  -1.70187592e+02 -2.35996841e+02 -2.96493286e+02 -3.39086365e+02
  -3.59514771e+02]
```

and the shape is `(13,33)`
Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please consider accepting (grey tick mark on the left of the answer) and/or upvoting the answer/s as a token of appreciation for help in solving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat similarly to the issue raised in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62561902/valueerror-illegal-value-in-4-th-argument-of-internal-none-when-running-sklearn) the issue is related to the intricacies of the underlying numerical operations that `librosa` defers to `scipy`. `SciPy` depends on LAPACK library being installed. So at first I would check [if you have it installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found).

Also, you may want to debug the script step-by-step to step into SciPy and examine actual values that are percolating from `librosa.feature.delta` to `scipy.signal.savgol_filter` which may tell you the reason when you cross-check them with [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html).